Can't get form elements to align properly using pymupdf and reportlab
I'm writing a program that takes form files and turns them into interactive PDF forms by using markers to locate and draw form elements.
I've gotten my radio buttons to align on the page properly but I cannot get my text boxes to align properly.
It seems it may be due to how the length of the preceding text is determined or possibly a difference in measurement units between packages but I can't seem to figure it out.
This code gets all the locations and dimensions of the form elements, writes them to a blank PDF, then merges that PDF with the original form:
def extract_pdf(filename):
    script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, filename)
    print(file_path)
    document = fitz.open(file_path)
    markers = []
    font = fitz.Font()
    print(document)


    for page_num in range(len(document)):
        page = document.load_page(page_num)
        text = page.get_text('dict')  
        for block in text['blocks']:
            for line in block['lines']:
                for span in line['spans']:
                    if '[' in span['text']:
                        bracket_matches = re.finditer(r'\[([^\]]*)\]', span['text'])
                        for match in bracket_matches:
                            start_index = match.start()
                            end_index = match.end()

                            preceding_text = span['text'][:start_index]
                            bracket_text = span['text'][start_index:end_index]
                                
                                
                            preceding_text_width = font.text_length(preceding_text, span['size'])
                            bracket_text_width = font.text_length(bracket_text, span['size'])                               

                            start_x = span['bbox'][0] + preceding_text_width
                            width = bracket_text_width
                            height = span['bbox'][3] - span['bbox'][1]
                            print(height)
                            markers.append({
                                "type": "text",
                                "x": start_x,
                                "y": span['bbox'][3],
                                "width": width,
                                'height': height,
                                "page_num": page_num
                                })               

    original_pdf = PdfReader(open(filename, 'rb'))
    output_pdf = PdfWriter()
    
    for i in range(len(original_pdf.pages)):
        original_page = original_pdf.pages[i]
        original_page_width = original_page.mediabox[2]
        original_page_height = original_page.mediabox[3]
        
        packet = io.BytesIO()
        can = canvas.Canvas(packet, pagesize=(original_page_width, original_page_height))
        acroform = can.acroForm
    
        text_counter = 1
        for marker in markers:
            text_counter += 1
            if marker["type"] == "text":
                acroform.textfield(
                    name=f"TextField{text_counter}",
                    x=marker['x'],
                    y=original_page_height - marker['y'],
                    width=marker['width'],
                    height=marker['height'],
                    borderStyle="solid",
                    borderWidth=1,
                    forceBorder=True,
                    maxlen=50            
                )
            
        can.save()

        packet.seek(0)
        new_pdf = PdfReader(packet)
        page = original_pdf.pages[i]
        if new_pdf.pages[0]:
            page.merge_page(new_pdf.pages[0])
        
        output_pdf.add_page(page)
        
    save_path  = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    save_file = os.path.join(script_dir, 'output.pdf')
    with open(save_file, 'wb') as f:
        output_pdf.write(f)
            

As you can see in the image, my radio buttons are about centered over their markers, however, my text boxes are all over the place. My text boxes in the header of the form are placed too far to the right on the X axis. My theory is that get_text_width isn't properly converting the preceding text width. Maybe whitespace isn't getting calculated properly? Everything looks in order when I print the preceding text and text length. Any guidance would be helpful.
This is what the form looks like prior:

This is the final form:


I don't think you should try to use Qt font capabilities to get the text size, as it will normally use the QApplication paint device as reference. As you can see, the first line shows that both "text boxes" are larger than they should, while, interestingly, the second line begins "later" than it should even though the preceding text is shorter. At the very least, you should rely on what the pymupdf library uses: for starters, Font().

@musicamante you're right I think I must have overlooked Font() in the docs. This fixes the width and placement in the 'Actionee' column, however, my text boxes in the form header have moved closer to their desired locations but are still offset to the right on the X axis. As before, the 2nd text boxes are offset further to the right than the first text boxes. The length seems to be spot on now though.

Then I suggest you to [edit] your post based on your changes. I also suggest to provide a more comprehensive [mre] within a single code block.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

@musicamante post updated and code cut down so its easy to reproduce

@BurgundyE30 You cannot just create an arbitrary, it has to be the same font and size used in the span.
